# Associação 1 para 1 Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Tenho um relacionamento entre Endereço e Academia onde 1 endereço tem 1 academia, e 1 academia tem 1 endereço.

Classe Academia:

```
public class Academia
{
    [Key]
    public int AcademiaID { get; set; }
    ...
    //relacionamentos
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Endereço

```
public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
    ...
    public int LocalID { get; set; }
    public virtual Local Local { get; set; }
}
```

Quando faço o `Enable-Migration` recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Academia.Models.Endereco' and 'Academia.Models.Academia'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Pelo que entendi, o entity não sabe definir quem é o principal entre as duas classes

Answer (score 1):

> pelo que entendi, o entity não sabe definir quem é o principal entre as duas classes.

Exato. E ele precisa saber. O "principal" é o model que pode existir independente do outro existir ou não, ou então, aquele que vai ser inserido primeiro. No exemplo, pela lógica, uma academia poderia existir sem um endereço, porém não se pode existir um endereço sem uma academia. Então, **`Academia`** é a parte principal desta relação.

**Como fazer isso**:

Marcando a propriedade principal como **`[Required]`** na classe não-principal.

```
public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Academia Academia { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando é um relacionamento 1 para 1, uma das pontas precisa ser a principal e a outra a dependente. A ponta principal será inserida primeiro no banco e pode existir sem a outra. Já a dependente deve ser inseria após a principal ser inserida, pois contém uma chave estrangeira para a principal.

Pode ser resolvido desta forma:

```
public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AcademiaId")]
    public virtual Academia Academia { get; set; }
}
```